# What is the best way to remove/delete a function object once instantiated/drawn to canvas?

Tags: javascript, canvas

The snippet code below shows a single function object called "Circle" being drawn to a canvas element. I know how to remove the *visual* aspect of the circle from the screen. I can simply change its opacity over time with `c.globalAlpha=0.0;` based on `event.listener` 's or 'object collision', However if I visually *undraw* said circle; it still is there and being computed on, its still taking up browser resources as it invisibly bounces to and fro on my canvas element.

So my question is: *What is the best way to remove/delete a function object once instantiated/drawn to canvas?* =>(so that it is truly removed and not invisibly bouncing in the browser)

```js
let canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
let c = canvas.getContext('2d');

function Circle(x, y, arc, dx, dy, radius){
  this.x = x;
  this.y = y;
  this.dx = dx;
  this.dy = dy;
  this.arc = arc;
  this.cCnt = 0;
  this.radius = radius;

  this.draw = function() {
    c.beginPath();
    //context.arc(x,y,r,sAngle,eAngle,counterclockwise);
    c.arc(this.x, this.y, this.radius, this.arc, Math.PI * 2, false); //
    c.globalAlpha=1;
    c.strokeStyle = 'pink';
    c.stroke();
  }

  this.update = function() {
    if (this.x + this.radius > canvas.width || this.x - this.radius < 0){
      this.dx = -this.dx;
    }
    if (this.y + this.radius > canvas.height || this.y - this.radius < 0){
      this.dy = -this.dy;
    }
    this.x += this.dx;
    this.y += this.dy;

    this.draw();
  }
}

var circle = new Circle(2, 2, 0, 1, 1, 2); // x, y, arc, xVel, yVel, radius

function animate() {
  requestAnimationFrame(animate);
  c.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height)
  circle.update();
}

animate();
```

```css
body {
      background-color: black;
      margin: 0;
    }
```

```html
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="200" height="60" style="background-color: white">
```

Comment: You could just stop calling `circle.update();`?

Comment: So maybe set a conditional to the update function? Then if the update function isn't called: then the function object remains in its last position from the last successful update?

Comment: Just stop referencing it and it'll be garbage collected automatically - if it's one object in an array of Circles or other things to be drawn, for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A lot of canvas libraries solve this problem by keeping an array of objects that are in the canvas scene. Every time the `animate()` function is called, it loops through the list of objects and calls `update()` for each one (I'm using the names you're using for simplicity).

This allows you to control what is in the scene by adding or removing objects from the array. Once objects are removed from the array, they will no longer be updated (and will get trash collected if there are no other references hanging around).

Here's an example:

```
const sceneObjects = [];

function animate() {
  requestAnimationFrame(animate);
  c.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

  // Update every object in the scene
  sceneObjects.forEach(obj => obj.update());
}

// Elsewhere...

function foo() {
  // Remove an object
  sceneObjects.pop();

  // Add a different object
  sceneObjects.push(new Circle(2, 2, 0, 1, 1, 2));
}
```

It's not uncommon to take this a step further by creating a `Scene` or `Canvas` class/object that keeps the list of scene objects and gives an interface for other parts of the program to use (for example, `Scene.add(myNewCircle)` or `Scene.remove(myOldCircle)`).

Comment: Ok I will try to replicate within my code, thank you.

Comment: just integrated you code and it works like a charm, thank-you.